# Request.CreateErrorResponse results in ProtocolViolationException - incorrect content length

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to set up a fairly straight forward NotModified status from a controller get method in Web API. I'm using the [Request.CreateErrorResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127065%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) extension method to streamline the process, but I'm getting a ProtocolViolationException thrown once the response gets returned:

```
response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotModified, "File up to date.");
```

I've worked around the issue for now by simply creating an empty response and setting the StatusCode:

```
response = Request.CreateResponse();
response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
```

The HttpConfiguration is set up to enable the XmlSerializer, and the JSON formatters are removed.

One explanation might be a bug somewhere behind the extension method code, but I can't help wondering if there's something else I'm missing here. Has anyone encountered this before, or have any explanations for how this would be triggered? I've included the stack trace for reference as well:

```
2014-07-01 02:41:16,505 [ERROR] [End][XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync] 
System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.
   at System.Net.HttpResponseStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.ByteBuffer.FlushAsync()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.DequeueAndFlush(ByteBuffer currentBuffer, AsyncEventArgsCallback callback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.FlushPendingBuffer()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.Flush()
   at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.Flush()
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.Flush()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass7.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)
```

Comment: The "Not Modified" response code shouldn't have a body, according to [this RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5): *The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.* Perhaps this is why you are getting a "protocol validation" and why it works once you only have the status code in the response without any content.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. The CreateErrorResponse() methods all require the status PLUS additional content (exception, string, dictionary or error).

Comment: Well, technically, the "Not Modified" response is not really an error if you think about it. It's just information that no further action is required.